# HashMap stuck on put

Tags: java, multithreading

I am coding on a multithreaded environment and I see threads are stuck on `HashMap.put`:

```
 34 Threads
 java.util.HashMap.put(HashMap.java:374) 
 com.aaa.bbb.MyClass.getDefinitionMap().
```

Investigating the method that is the `HashMap` I see that the method is synchronized:

```
@Override
public synchronized Map<String,String> getDefinitionMap() {
        //truncated some code here...
        colDefMap = new HashMap<String,String>();           
        for (CD cd : (List<CD>)cm.getDef()) {
            colDefMap.put(cd.getIdentifier(),cd);
        }
    return colDefMap;
}
```

So after switching to `ConcurrentHashMap`, removing the synchronized keyword from the method signature and restarting the application server - problem is resolved.

My question is why synchronized method is not sufficient in this scenario to protect the map from concurrent access?

Comment: Very hard to tell without a [mcve]. Do your equals/hashCode methods call anything else that's synchronized, possibly causing a deadlock?

Comment: What exactly are you synchronizing access to? You're creating the `HashMap` in the method, so there is no risk with this method interfering with another thread's map. You only need to synchronize access to shared state, so maybe you need to synchronize access to `cm`?

Comment: Most likely a cause of deadlock somewhere. You have to check all your methods that may also have a sync call. There isn't enough code to know for sure. But I'd be curious if there are other methods in that class that are synced. What about `cm`. Is there a lock on that. .

Comment: Samuel is also right. There is no sync needed.

Comment: how can you add `cd` to the map? It is instance of `CD` other than `String`

Comment: Why is `colDefMap` (not the greatest variable name) not declared inside the method?

Comment: its a class variable, in the super class                def:      protected Map<String,String> colDefMap;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't say how "stuck" this is, whether you actually have a deadlock or a bottleneck.

I would expect the posted code to be a bottleneck, where almost all your threads are trying to access the same object, waiting on acquiring the lock used by the synchronized method. It's likely that whatever cm.getDef does takes a while and only one thread at a time can make progress. So synchronizing does protect the data from concurrent access, just at the expense of throughput.

This fits the definition of "starvation" given in [the Java concurrency tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/starvelive.html):

> Starvation describes a situation where a thread is unable to gain regular access to shared resources and is unable to make progress. This happens when shared resources are made unavailable for long periods by "greedy" threads. For example, suppose an object provides a synchronized method that often takes a long time to return. If one thread invokes this method frequently, other threads that also need frequent synchronized access to the same object will often be blocked.

Switching to ConcurrentHashMap is a good improvement, as you observed. ConcurrentHashMap avoids locking threads out of the entire map, and supports concurrent updates, see [the API doc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ConcurrentHashMap.html) (my emphasis):

> A hash table supporting full concurrency of retrievals and high expected concurrency for updates. This class obeys the same functional specification as Hashtable, and includes versions of methods corresponding to each method of Hashtable. However, **even though all operations are thread-safe, retrieval operations do not entail locking, and there is not any support for locking the entire table in a way that prevents all access.** This class is fully interoperable with Hashtable in programs that rely on its thread safety but not on its synchronization details.

You might consider caching whatever cm.getDef does so you don't have to call it every time, but the practicality of that will depend on your requirements, of course.

Comment: If a bottleneck was there, ConcurrentHashMap will not resolve the issue, correct?

Comment: @user648026: it should resolve the issue, because there is dramatically less locking going on.

Answer (score 2):

You were synchronizing on the `getDefinitionMap` method in the subclass, which is *apparently* not the only method (or class) that has access to `cm`.

The iterator on the class variable `cm` is the likely culprit:

```
for (CD cd : (List<CD>) cm.getDef())
{
    colDefMap.put(cd.getIdentifier(), cd);
}
```

In the above code, the `cm` variable is likely being modified while you are iterating over it.

You could have used the following:

```
synchronized (cm)
{
    for (CD cd : (List<CD>) cm.getDef())
    {
        colDefMap.put(cd.getIdentifier(), cd);
    }
}
```

However, this would have still left modification of `cm` open to other threads, if modifications to `cm` were performed without similar synchronization.

As you discovered, it is much easier to use the thread-safe versions of the collections classes than to implement workarounds for non-thread-safe collections in a multi-threaded environment.

Comment: So setting synchronized on your method signature will not prevent a race condition?

Comment: @user648026 In order to answer that question, you need to consider what you are potentially racing against. Setting a method to `synchronized` only prevents simultaneous invocations of that method. However, some other method might be modifying that variable independently, and setting `synchronized` on both methods won't even solve that problem. Imagine a house with two doors (front and back), and you put a doorman at each door with instructions to only allow one person in the house at a time. The doormen don't talk to each other and you end up with two people in the house.

Answer (score 2):

I think you may be wrong by thinking that you solve your problem. Removing the **synchronized** means that you unlock access to this method which can resolve your problem and brings others. I mean your HashMap is created in the scope of your function so its obviously not here that you should have a concurrency probleme (if what is put inside is not static or thread-Safe). Never the less here using concurrentHashMap has no effect.

I suggest you to try and see in a multi-thread test if your function do properly is job without the synchronized statement (without the concurrentMap).

In my opinion without knowing the rest of your code, this function may be accessing static or shared data that may be lock by a thread so the problem do not come from the function but an other object interacting with it at some point.

Answer (score 1):

Are you modifying it anywhere else? Are you 100% sure it's not being `put` somewhere else? I suspect you are and what is likely is that the second put is causing an infinite loop. http://mailinator.blogspot.com/2009/06/beautiful-race-condition.html

Otherwise, if this is the only place you are modifying the `HashMap`, it should be fine.